# Unable to view OpenTelemetry Span Events in Elastic APM traces's logs

Tags: node.js, open-telemetry, elastic-apm

I am trying to set up OpenTelemetry in a distributed Nodejs application. I am using elastic APM to view those traces and respective spans. For exporting those span data to elastic APM I have an otel Collector on K8s. The issue is that I can see the span events in elastic index but those span event details are not visible in traces' logs as mentioned  [here](https://github.com/elastic/apm-server/pull/6122) 
 Is there any work around for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was because of a bug in elastic APM version 8.4.0 as mentioned [here](https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/139631) . It can be fixed by upgrading to any version above 8.4.1 that it 8.4.2 or 8.5. It can also be fixed by downgrading to a version below 8.4.0. For me version 7.0.0 worked.